# Why does this matrix convolution lead to circular symmetry?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

An array evolves discretely in time following the equation

$$c_{i,j}(t+1)=\frac{p}{4}[c_{i-1,j}(t)+c_{i,j-1}(t)+c_{i+1,j}(t)+c_{i,j+1}(t)]+(1-p)c_{i,j}(t)$$

And the initial condition is $c_{i,j}(0)=\delta_i\delta_j$. I thought the result should have the same symmetry as the matrix

$$\pmatrix{0 & p/4 & 0 \\ p/4 & 1-p & p/4\\0 & p/4 & 0}$$

But apparently it has circular symmetry, at least around the origin. Is there an intuitive way to understand this?

[image: A 51x51 matrix with periodic boundary]

Comment: What is the dimension? Does $\delta_i\delta_j$ mean $\delta_{ij}$? Is this true for any $p$?

Comment: @thedude The problem is set in 2d, and circular symmetry holds for any $0<p<1$ (at least the ones I tested :). $\delta_i\delta_j$ is just the multiple of two delta functions, so at $t=0$, $c_{ij}$ is 1 at the origin, and zero everywhere else.

Comment: This is an FTCS scheme for a diffusion equation in two dimensions (where $p$ is proportional to $\frac{k \Delta t}{\Delta x^2}$ and $k$ is the diffusion constant). It is not quite isotropic (because all hops are along a coordinate axis), but it is close, especially if things are scaled so that $\Delta x$ is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evolution equation is morally very similar to a [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation) 
$$ \frac{\partial c(x,y)}{\partial t}=\nabla^2c(x,y)$$
So it is not surpring that it shows similar behavior, namely any initial condition will spread in time to a Gaussian distribution with circular symmetry.